# Error when trying to switch back to the original browser window using intern leadfoot

Tags: intern, leadfoot

I'm getting the following error when I call switchToWindow(handle):
null value in entry: name=null

The original window is still open when I try to switch and handle is not null or empty.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
var session = this.remote;
var handle;

return session
    .get('http://www.google.com')
    .getCurrentWindowHandle()
    .then(function (currentHandle) {
        console.log('handle: ' + currentHandle);
        handle = currentHandle;
    })
    .execute(function() {
        var newWindow = window.open('https://www.instagram.com/', 'insta');
    })
    .switchToWindow('insta')
    .closeCurrentWindow()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('old handle: ' + handle);
    })
    .sleep(2000)
    .switchToWindow(handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Command chain is a single JavaScript expression. This means that all the arguments to all the calls in the chain are evaluated at once, synchronously. When `handle` is assigned in a `then` callback near the top of the chain, it won't affect the `switchToWindow` call at the bottom of the chain, because the value of `handle` had already been evaluated before the `then` callback ever executed.

If you want to keep a reference to a value early in a chain, and use it later, both uses should be in `then` callbacks.

```
return session
    ...
    .then(function (currentHandle) {
        handle = currentHandle;
    })
    ...
    .then(function () {
        return session.switchToWindow(handle);
    });
```